# JSF Url Decoding Greek Characters

Tags: jsf, decoding

Im having some issues with jsf files not passing the correct Greek Character to its controller as a

```
<f:viewParam>
```

Currently I am encoding the α (alpha) character and passing it off in the url which is encoded to: https://rooturl?tag=%CE%B1+testing

however when im implementing the

```
<f:viewParam name="tag" value="#{controller.itemName}" />
```

to set the beans value it is instead setting it to the Î± testing value.

Sofar ive tried to implement a "CharacterEncodingFilter" as suggested in other websites with the context:

```
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

/** The default character encoding to set for request / response. */
private String encoding = null;

/** The filter configuration object. */
private FilterConfig filterConfig;

/** Should a character encoding specified by the client be ignored? */
private boolean ignore = true;

public void destroy() {
    encoding = null;
    filterConfig = null;
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
    // conditionally select and set the character encoding to be used
    if ((ignore || (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null)) && (encoding != null)) {
        request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
    }

    // pass control on to the next filter
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    this.encoding = filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");

    String value = filterConfig.getInitParameter("ignore");

    this.ignore = ((value == null) || value.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || value.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
}
}
```

and added the filter to the web.xml file

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>mypackage.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>override any encodings from client</description>
        <param-name>ignore</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <description>the encoding to use</description>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/myurl/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

ive also modified the xhtml file to include the

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

tag as suggested on other websites. However none of these modifications have seemed to change the behavior and am still getting the incorrect character.

Any help on how to get the JSF to pick up the correct value would be much appreciated.

Comment: What container do you happen to use? If for example, you are using Tomcat then, do `<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" />` in `server.xml`. Going a bit ahead : How do you verify that the given `<f:viewParam>` sets the corresponding bean property with a value of `Î±`, when `α` is passed, by displaying it on the console? If it is the case, then that perception is not true. Try re-displaying it on the browser itself or any other device supporting `UTF-8`. That `<meta>` tag is needed but not related. It comes into play, only when you open a web page directly from the local disk file system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im using a jboss server and havent modified any of its configurations yet. Hoping to avoid that.

Yes im viewing the
    Î±

 character in the console itself. Ill try to view it in something else that supports UTF-8.

Comment: JBoss or WildFly? The former uses Apache Tomcat and the the latter uses undertow as their Servlet container. Both have different ways to set encoding.

Comment: Jboss

And looked at the character codes being returned. The character number (206 and 177) does match with the Î± characters being returned.

Comment: I am not concerned with earlier versions of WildFly thus, JBoss but these two properties need to be set in `standalone-xxx-yyy.xml` as mentioned in the first snippet [here](https://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.3.0.CR1/reference/html/i18n.html). (There would be a different story, if it were WildFly).

Comment: Nice that did it! Do you think i can delete all of the filter mapping and filter code i had before?

Comment: Tested and i dont, post that as the answer if you want and ill flag it as correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes it is not needed. You can safely delete that filter (A filter would have been needed for POST request parameters, if it had been JSP). You will want to read up [this](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) entire blog at leisure.